# Does Google App Engine allow file caching (using Django)?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am seeing a problem that Django's file-based caching is not functional in Google App Engine. Ideally I want to use commands such as below to read/write from a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

```
output = cache.get(cacheKey)
#or
cache.set(cacheKey, output, timeout = 60*15)
```

I have seen some articles on memcaching, but that is not what I need.

Is it possible to combine Django's file-based caching with Google Cloud Storage? How do I perform this (and what permission settings are required?)

Answer (score 1):

Update: writing to a local directory is forbidden by Google app engine, they insist you use Google storage. Getting Django's caching to read/write from google storage is also impossible because it requires interacting with an API that is not internal to Django.

So what to do? I was close to replicating Djangos caching by just using pickling and this gcsfs library, like this:

```
import gcsfs 
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-project')
pickle.dump(output,fs.open('my-project.appspot.com/myfile.p', 'wb'))
```

Fun fact, pandas is also equipped to write directly to GCS

```
from google.cloud import storage
output.to_csv('gs://my-project.appspot.com/filename.csv')
```

While both these method work, any method is extremely slow (especially to write). For my object it took 45-65 seconds to write and 5-7 seconds to read (compared to local pickling which are both like under 1 seconds). The is really bad for my app:-(

It's too bad [Google App Engine doesn't allow writing to its local filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage). Maybe I'll have to use something else like Compute Engine (hopefully it allows it)